# How to append multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to append two lists `A[0]` and `A` but I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
A=[]
A[0]=[np.array([[0.4]])]
A=[np.array([[0.15]])]
print("A =",A)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    A[0]=[np.array([[0.4]])]

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[0.4]]),
 array([[0.15]])]
```

Comment: Why not directly use `A = [array([[0.4]]), array([[0.15]])]` as you type the arrays anyways? Or maybe you're not faithfully illustrating your real goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `A[0]` is not a list; it's an element (the first one, to be precise) in list `A`. But `A` is empty, so there is no element `A[0]`in it that you can assign a value to, hence the "index out of range" error. Try the following instead:

```
import numpy as np
A=[]
A.append(np.array([[0.4]]))
A.append(np.array([[0.15]]))
print("A =",A)
```